Is it necessary to pass SharePoint site GUID in Graph API using [Hostname,site GUID,WebGUID] format?
While accessing any SharePoint resources through Graph API, do we really need to specify the Site_ID in the "Hostname,SP-site-col-GUID,web-Guid" format ?
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{Site_ID}}/lists/{{list_ID}}
I am asking this because, the format of the Graph API says to pass site GUID, we should have only pass the actual site GUID instead of in above format. but direct GUID passing says the site is not found.
Why this is so? or there is any other way to address this and I am doing it in wrong way.
Please help me clarifying above.
Thanks in advance!

The site Id is a unique ID that is a composite of the hostname, the site collection GUID, and the site GUID. It looks something like this:
robwindsortest980.sharepoint.com,130df549-fe92-4160-a4d6-151b48335fa2,427124d7-af02-4009-97f6-5b7c1d17873f
To get this site by the site Id, you would make a GET request to:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/robwindsortest980.sharepoint.com,5c269f43-747d-4589-93fb-90af4f150b6a,427124d7-af02-4009-97f6-5b7c1d17873f
If you have the server-relative URL for a site resource, you can instead use a composite of the hostname and the server-relative URL to the site. It looks something like this:
robwindsortest980.sharepoint.com:/sites/Demo
To get this site by the server-relative URL, you would make a GET request to:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/robwindsortest980.sharepoint.com:/sites/Demo
To access a list named Products from the site used in the examples above, you can use either of these GET requests:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/robwindsortest980.sharepoint.com,5c269f43-747d-4589-93fb-90af4f150b6a,427124d7-af02-4009-97f6-5b7c1d17873f/lists/Products
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/robwindsortest980.sharepoint.com:/sites/Demo:/lists/Products
For more information see:
Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph
Access a SharePoint site by server-relative URL with Microsoft Graph

Why is not enough to specify only the site GUID? The site GUID should be unique across all site collections.

That would be a question for the team at Microsoft that designed the Graph APIs.
